# Jinja2 template over a json file

Tags: json, templates, jinja2

I'm trying to run a jinja 2 template over a json.
This is the json file I have:

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "Apps": [
                  {
            "owner": "owner1",
            "AppNm": "App1"
          }
                ],
        "server": "server1"
    },
        {
        "Apps": [
                  {
            "owner": "owner3",
            "AppNm": "App1"
          },
                  {
            "owner": "owner2",
            "AppNm": "App2"
          }
                ],
        "server": "server2"
        }
  ]
}
```

This is the template I'm working:

```
{%- set app_srv = {} -%}
{%- set apps_list = [] -%}
{%- set owners_list = [] -%}

{%- for srv_chg in server_changes.results -%}
        {%- for srv_chg_item in srv_chg.Apps -%}
                {%- if srv_chg_item.AppNm not in apps_list -%}
                        {{ apps_list.append( srv_chg_item.AppNm ) }}
                {%- endif -%}
        {%- endfor -%}
{%- endfor -%}

{%- for apps_item in apps_list -%}
        {%- for srv_chg in server_changes.results -%}
                {%- for srv_chg_item in srv_chg.Apps -%}
                        {%- if srv_chg_item.owner not in owners_list and srv_chg_item.AppNm == apps_item -%}
                                {{ owners_list.append( srv_chg_item.owner ) }}
                        {%- endif -%}
                {%- endfor -%}
        {%- endfor -%}
        {{ app_srv.update({apps_item: {'owner': owners_list}}) }}
{%- endfor -%}

{{ app_srv|to_nice_json }}
```

The basic idea is to reorganize the json in a application/server fashion instead of server/application.

This is the output I'm getting from the template:

```
{
    "App1": {
        "owner": [
            "owner1",
            "owner3",
            "owner2"
        ]
    },
    "App2": {
        "owner": [
            "owner1",
            "owner3",
            "owner2"
        ]
    }
}
```

This the output I need from the template:

```
{
    "App1": {
        "owner": [
            "owner1",
            "owner3"
        ]
    },
    "App2": {
        "owner": [
            "owner2"
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm having a problem with the *owners_list*. I though that when the *apps_list* loops, the *owners_list* will reset.
I don't understand how to manage the list in that situation.

Any help will be appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was rather simple.

```
{%- set app_srv = {} -%}
{%- set apps_list = [] -%}
{%- set owners_list = [] -%}

{%- for srv_chg in server_changes.results -%}
        {%- for srv_chg_item in srv_chg.Apps -%}
                {%- if srv_chg_item.AppNm not in apps_list -%}
                        {{ apps_list.append( srv_chg_item.AppNm ) }}
                {%- endif -%}
        {%- endfor -%}
{%- endfor -%}

{%- for apps_item in apps_list -%}
        {%- set owners_list = [] -%}
        {%- for srv_chg in server_changes.results -%}
                {%- for srv_chg_item in srv_chg.Apps -%}
                        {%- if srv_chg_item.owner not in owners_list and srv_chg_item.AppNm == apps_item -%}
                                {{ owners_list.append( srv_chg_item.owner ) }}
                        {%- endif -%}
                {%- endfor -%}
        {%- endfor -%}
        {{ app_srv.update({apps_item: {'owner': owners_list}}) }}
{%- endfor -%}

{{ app_srv|to_nice_json }}
```

After the FOR for apps_list, I added a {%- set owners_list = [] -%}.
Tried to do the same before the end of the first for, but it didn't work.